# Relative record for loop each input and correct duplicate record

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My form record a JSON array including name and value of each input.
I'm trying to add an "optionprix" attribute for each input class "optionname" based on the relative value of input class "optionprix".

My html form :

```
<div id="sortables-form">
<ul id="sortables"><li>
<input name="checkboxes-label" value="Options" type="text">
<ul id="checkboxes">                         
<li>
<input class="optionname" name="checkbox-2778418" value="Option1" optionprix="5" type="text">
<input class="optionprix" name="checkbox-2778418" value="5" type="text">
</li>
<li>
<input class="optionname" name="checkbox-2778419" value="Option2" optionprix="10" type="text">
<input class="optionprix" name="checkbox-2778419" value="10" type="text">
</li>
<li>
<input class="optionname" name="checkbox-2778420" value="Option3" optionprix="15" type="text">
<input class="optionprix" name="checkbox-2778420" value="15" type="text">
</li>
</ul>
<button class="saveButton" data-type="single-checkbox">Save</button>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

My javascript function :

```
function update_CF_Data(CF_SortablesForm){
    var mySelector = $("sortables-form");
    var data_array = new Array();
    $("#sortables-form :input").not("#sortables-form :input[class=optionprix]").each(function(){

        var item = {};
        item['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
        item['value'] = $(this).attr('value');

        var optionPrix = $("#sortables-form li input[class=optionprix]").val();

        if ($(this).hasClass('optionname')){
        item['optionprix'] = optionPrix;
        }

        data_array.push(item);

    });
    var sortableContent = JSON.stringify(data_array);
    $('#myparentform').val(sortableContent);

    console.log(data_array);
};
```

The JSON record :

```
array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(18) "required---2778418" ["value"]=> string(2) "on" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(26) "checkboxes-label" ["value"]=> string(7) "Options" } [2]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(25) "checkbox-2778418" ["value"]=> string(7) "Option1" ["optionprix"]=> string(1) "5" } [3]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(25) "checkbox-2778419" ["value"]=> string(7) "Option2" ["optionprix"]=> string(1) "5" } [4]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(25) "checkbox-2778420" ["value"]=> string(7) "Option3" ["optionprix"]=> string(1) "5" } [5]=> array(0) { } }
```

Actually all data recorded take the first record of my input class="optionprix" and print 5 as value.

I tried to change my javascript code to reach my goal, without success ...

Perhaps I that's in relation with the exclude part *.not("#sortables-form :input[class=optionprix]")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the same value each time becuase you are not using `$(this)` when fetching the value of the corresponding `optionprix` textbox (of that iteration). 
You can use the `siblings()` method in JQuery to access the adjacent element's value.

[siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Try this,

```
function update_CF_Data(CF_SortablesForm){
    var mySelector = $("sortables-form");
    var data_array = new Array();
    $("#sortables-form :input").not("#sortables-form :input[class=optionprix]").each(function(){

        var item = {};
        item['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
        item['value'] = $(this).attr('value');

        //var optionPrix = $("#sortables-form li input[class=optionprix]").val();
        var optionPrix = $(this).siblings("input.optionprix").val();

        if ($(this).hasClass('optionname')){
        item['optionprix'] = optionPrix;
        }

        data_array.push(item);

    });
    var sortableContent = JSON.stringify(data_array);
    $('#myparentform').val(sortableContent);

    console.log(data_array);
};
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's the perfect function for my goal :)